# Using an AutoComplete Extender without webservice

Tags: asp.net

I have a dynamic data web site into which I am attempting to add a text box with an AutoCompleteExtender. I have declared the control like so

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbTerm" runat="server" Width="300px"/>
  <asp:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server"
       id="autoCompleteExtenderTerms"
       TargetControlID="tbTerm" 
       ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" 
       UseContextKey="True">
  </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

And in the codebehind on that page I have declared the web method like so

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public static List<string> GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
{
    using (ProductDataEntities context = new ProductDataEntities())
    {
        var terms = (from t in context.Terms
                     where t.Name.StartsWith(prefixText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                     select t.Name).ToList();

        return terms;
    }
}
```

Currently this method is not getting called, this is not a forgien key column so I cant use the standard filter for this.

I have ensured that EnablePageMethods="true" is set on the ScriptManager and I am out of ideas as to why this method is not being fired from the page.The contol is not wrapped within an update panel nothing else stands out to me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Set up `ServicePath` property value.

Comment: shoot, no dice. Tried ~/DynamicData/CustomPages/Terms/List.aspx, ~/DynamicData/CustomPages/Terms/List.aspx.cs, /DynamicData/CustomPages/Terms/List.aspx, /DynamicData/CustomPages/Terms/List.aspx.cs